# get error Directory.Move() c#

Tags: c#, directory, rename

I tried to run this code:

```
Directory.Move("C:\\ABC", "C:\\abc");
```

but I get this error:

> "Source and destination path must be different."

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Directory.Move` operation is case insensitive.

The easiest solution would be to move it twice, once to a temp folder, and then once to the correct folder.

If the operation fails it's best to provide some rollback functionality.

```
Directory.Move("C:\\ABC", "C:\\ABCTEMP");
try {
    Directory.Move("C:\\ABCTEMP", "C:\\abc");
} catch (IOException) {
    Directory.Move("C:\\ABCTEMP", "C:\\ABC");
} catch (UnauthorizedAccesException) {
    Directory.Move("C:\\ABCTEMP", "C:\\ABC");
}
```